# how to find my previously set log4j level

Tags: java, log4j

Am looking for help for my assignment in finding out log4j level after setting the same. I tried searching but couldn't find any help. Please excuse for the poor question as am still a learner.

**As we have setLevel(), do we have anything to get this level somewhere after it is set? Something as getLevel() which returns previously set level.**

```
 private static Logger logger;
 ........
 ........
 logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);    --setting the level


 //do we have something wherein we can get the level which was set?
 int value = logger.getLevel();  --can this be done?
```

Comment: Log4j `Logger` class inherits `getLevel()` method from its parent: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log4j `Logger` class inherits `getLevel()` method from its parent: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html

This method returns `Level` instance but you can get int value:

```
Level level = logger.getLevel();
int levelInt = level.toInt();
```